# How Can I put an Image on another Image that i am taking from you tube?

Tags: android

Problem is that I am taking thumbnail  from Youtube of the video and when I am clicking on that Image that is redirecting me to Youtube but problem is that i want to show the image of a play Icon on that Image that I am taking from Youtube..Hope so u have Understood what I am asking.
        can any One Help me.
        package com.dotocto.ipartner;

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.dotocto.ipartner.dataset.VedioDataSet;
    import com.dotocto.ipartner.netio.WebServices;
    import com.dotocto.ipartner.patten.ImageLoader;
    import com.dotocto.ipartner.patten.UtilClassForValidations;

    public class VideoScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        private ImageView[] images;
        private ImageLoader imageloader;
        //private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView vedio_text;
        private LinearLayout image_layout;
        ArrayList<VedioDataSet> imageslist;
        ImageView i11;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.video_screen);
            try{
                vedio_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vedio_text);

                image_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.image_layout);

                imageloader = new ImageLoader(VideoScreen.this);

                imageslist = new ArrayList<VedioDataSet>();
    i11= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStart();
            try{
                LinearLayout vedio_lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.vedio_lay); 
                vedio_lay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected);

                vedio_text .setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLUE);

                if(imageslist == null || imageslist.size() <= 0)
                {
                    new PostDataToServer().execute();
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

        class PostDataToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<VedioDataSet>>  {

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<VedioDataSet> doInBackground(String... arg0) 
            {
                return WebServices.VedioActivity();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<VedioDataSet > result)//onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter. 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //          if(pd != null && pd.isShowing())
                //              pd.dismiss();
                try{
                    if(result != null)
                    {
                        if(result.get(0).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
                        {
                            imageslist = result;

                            for(int j=0; j<imageslist.size(); j++)
                            {                                       
                                LinearLayout hlinearlayout = new LinearLayout(VideoScreen.this);
                                hlinearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        1f);
                                hlinearlayout.setWeightSum(3);

                                final VedioDataSet record1 = imageslist.get(j);

                                ImageView img1 = new ImageView(VideoScreen.this);
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = layoutParams;
                                params1.weight = 1f;
                                params1.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
                                img1.setLayoutParams(params1);
                                img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                img1.setTag(record1.getYoutubeimg());
                                //i11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                imageloader.DisplayImage(record1.getYoutubeimg(), VideoScreen.this, img1);
                                hlinearlayout.addView(img1);
                                playVideo(img1,record1);
                                j ++;

                                if(j < imageslist.size())
                                {   
                                    final VedioDataSet record2 = imageslist.get(j);
                                    ImageView img2 = new ImageView(VideoScreen.this);
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = layoutParams;
                                    params2.weight = 1f;
                                    params2.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
                                    img2.setLayoutParams(params2);
                                    img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    img2.setTag(record2.getYoutubeimg());

                                    imageloader.DisplayImage(record2.getYoutubeimg(), VideoScreen.this, img2);
                                    hlinearlayout.addView(img2);
                                    playVideo(img2,record2);
                                }
                                j++;

                                if(j < imageslist.size())
                                {   
                                    final VedioDataSet record3 = imageslist.get(j);
                                    ImageView img3 = new ImageView(VideoScreen.this);
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = layoutParams;
                                    params3.weight = 1f;
                                    params3.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
                                    img3.setLayoutParams(params3);
                                    img3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    img3.setTag(record3.getYoutubeimg());

                                    imageloader.DisplayImage(record3.getYoutubeimg(), VideoScreen.this, img3);
                                    hlinearlayout.addView(img3);
                                    playVideo(img3,record3);
                                }
                                image_layout.addView(hlinearlayout);                        
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            UtilClassForValidations.alatMassageBox(VideoScreen.this,result.get(0).getErrormsg() );
                    }
                    else
                        UtilClassForValidations.alatMassageBox(VideoScreen.this, "We're sorry! There has been some error " +
                                "occured during serching video screen images and vedios. Please try again after some time.");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void playVideo(ImageView x ,final VedioDataSet y){

            x.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {                                   
                    try 
                    {
                        if(y.getVideourl() != null && y.getVideourl().length() >0)
                        {
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse(y.getVideourl());              
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            //  finish();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            UtilClassForValidations.alatMassageBox(VideoScreen.this, "We're sorry! " +
                                    " The video Url is can not provided by server side" +
                                    " Please try again after some time.");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
            switch (v.getId()) 
            {
            case R.id.give_icon:
                Intent give = new Intent(VideoScreen.this, PaymentActivity.class);
                give.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(give);        
                //  finish();
                break;

            case R.id.blog_icon:
                Intent blog = new Intent(VideoScreen.this, BlogActivity.class);
                blog.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(blog);        
                //      finish();
                break;

            case R.id.arms_icon:
                Intent vedio = new Intent(VideoScreen.this, PartnershipArms.class);
                vedio.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(vedio);       
                //  finish();
                break;

            case R.id.icon_contact:
                Intent contact = new Intent(VideoScreen.this, ContactUsActivity.class);
                contact.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(contact);     


                //      finish(;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

// this is my XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/inner_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_bg" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_bar_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="VIDEOS"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:typeface="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_bar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_ineerlayout2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3" >
<FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/par_arm3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/bottom_bg" 
                    />"

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/play_btn1" 
                    android:keepScreenOn="true"
                    android:clickable="true"/>

</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/par_arm4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_holder" />
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/play_btn1" 

                    android:keepScreenOn="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/par_arm5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_holder" />
                   <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/play_btn1" />

</RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_ineerlayout3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/par_arm6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_holder" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/play_btn1" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/par_arm7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_holder" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/play_btn1" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/par_arm8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_holder" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/play_btn1" />
     </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_ineerlayout4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/par_arm9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_holder" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/play_btn1" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/par_arm10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_holder" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView88"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/play_btn1"
                    android:keepScreenOn="true" />

     </RelativeLayout>
     <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    >
                         <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/par_arm11"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_holder" />
                         <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView77"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/play_btn1" 
                    android:keepScreenOn="true"/>

     </RelativeLayout>
                         </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bott_iner_linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.dotocto.ipartner.patten.SAutoBgButton
                    android:id="@+id/arms_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/arms_icon"
                    android:onClick="onClick" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="ARMS"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:typeface="normal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.dotocto.ipartner.patten.SAutoBgButton
                    android:id="@+id/give_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/give_icon"
                    android:onClick="onClick" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/give_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="GIVE"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:typeface="normal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.dotocto.ipartner.patten.SAutoBgButton
                    android:id="@+id/blog_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blog_icon"
                    android:onClick="onClick" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:text="BLOG"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:typeface="normal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.dotocto.ipartner.patten.SAutoBgButton
                    android:id="@+id/vedio_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/vedio_icon"
                    android:onClick="onClick" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vedio_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:text="VIDEO"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:typeface="normal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.dotocto.ipartner.patten.SAutoBgButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon_contact"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_contact"
                    android:onClick="onClick" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="CONTACT US"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:typeface="normal" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i am using relative layout but when i am doing this the upper image view get dissappear.

Answer (score 0):

to use overlapping images in layout you can use frame layout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html